# Magento 2.1 order history items link

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, customer-account

How to add product link and image on my customer panel, my order, view order tab?
by default it just shows title of product with no link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define

```
$url = $this->getOrderItem()->getProduct()->getProductUrl();
```

and add

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">your page title</a>
```